# PHP Securing Webpages: Restricted Area

Tags: php, html, mysql

My login is not very secure, I wanted to just show the pages when I login, but I can explicitly call them all from the browser. How can I easily restrict these pages so no one sees if logged out :-(

Comment: I would suggest looking at the tizag tutorials on session data and how it works - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php but you'll also need to look at tutorials regarding storing credentials in databases, hashing passwords etc,. The question is very hard to answer specifically

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. I have hash password and sessions, but something I am doing wrong as if I type explicitly the address of the page, it shows.

Comment: Most likely those scripts aren't doing any checking to make sure that the user is logged in. Generally what I find is easiest to is to have a script that does the security and every page loads it - include("security.php"), and you're security script will have a session_start(); line and then you can do all your user validation in the "security.php" script and any script calling "security.php" will have access to the session data and the user validation. There is more to it than that but that's a push in the general direction.

Comment: Good advice, but isn't long to have all user checks in a file? I have a checkLogin and checkRegistration file, is it about the same you mentioned, or uours is a file with the php session variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['userID'];

if(!isset($session))
{
 die("You must be logged in"); //Or whatever else you may do, such as take them to the homepage.
}
```

Again, this is very basic - it's apparent that you don't have a very high level of knowledge about PHP, security, or any of the related.

Comment: I am learning by myself :-( so where do I place this code, on top of all pages and that is it?

Comment: I have <?php session_start(); ?> on top of all pages so it means I will have a session and the pages will always show, right?

Comment: No problem - I just updated my answer some, but yes you would have this code on top of each of your page. You have to create a session when a user logs in, which I would hope you are doing otherwise `session_start()` is actually useless.

Comment: It's a project where I need to learn PHP by myself so that is why I am all newbie and confused, but I I'll learn. :-)

Comment: Well using the code that I provided above should work for what you want, there are other ways as gd1 mentioned with .htaccess, however that is more than likely something that you may not be up to mess around with at this point.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I placed the code on top of a page, but it still allowed the page to be seen and also showed all the code on the page.  did as suggested, a page that called security.php then I included on http://www3.londonmet.ac.uk:8008/~iia0014/managerInterface.php and you can check the result.

Comment: Is that code wrapped in `<?php ?>` tags? They either are not, or are being `echoed` or `printed` out.

Comment: It is fine but still you can go to http://www3.londonmet.ac.uk:8008/~iia0014/managerInterface.php even though this code is properly on top. It should not show the page if I am not logged in.

Comment: It doesn't show the page for me, it says that I am not logged in just as it should.

Comment: I need to try in another computer as I am logged out and I can see the page, maybe I have a problem with my loggout, but I dont think so.

Comment: As long as you are destroying the session on log out, it should be fine.

Comment: You were right,on another pc it works, but on my computer it shows. I do have a problem with my logout <?php

session_start();
unset($_SESSION['myusername']);
$_SESSION['myusername']='';
//session_destroy($_SESSION['myusername']);
header('location: index.php');
?>

Comment: All fixed now. Thank you, even though a lot of people hated this question, I got really good links, advice, a better understanding of security and my problem sorted completely.

Comment: Ok fantastic glad you got it fixed. (Yes people on here forget that there ARE beginners out there.) ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have got to learn a basic subset of PHP, including session management. Alternatively, or in the meanwhile, you can just secure a directory using an .htaccess

Comment: @learnerNo1: You could read the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html#auth).